# delete rows depending on 3 values

Tags: php, html

i have issues arising with deleting a row. the issues are that i want to delete a row that has the same ID but multiple rows. i want to make sure that i can delete a row not only with the ID but also the week, day and shift to delete a specific row.

this is the code when i click the delete button

```
 <td><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel Shift?')" href="remove.php? delete=<?php echo $row['employeeID'].'week='&$row['week'].'day='&$row['day'].'shift='&$row['shift']?>" class="btn del">Cancel</a></td>
```

this is the code to deleting my row

```
          <?php 
          include_once'../dbconfig/DBConn.php';
          $con = DBConn::getConnection();

         if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
                $delete= $_GET['delete'];
                $week = $_GET['week'];
                $day = $_GET['day'];
                $shift = $_GET['shift'];
                $result = $con->query("DELETE FROM empavailability WHERE employeeID = 
                $delete AND week= $week AND day=$day AND $shift");
                if($result){
                     //header('location: EmpView.php');
               }else{
                   ?>
              <script>
                      alert("Failed to cancel Shift");
                      window.location.href='EmpView.php';
              </script>
              <?php 
        }
    }
    ?>
```

These are the errors i am receiving
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `&` characters in the wrong place in your URL.

```
<td><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel Shift?')" href="remove.php?delete=<?php echo $row['employeeID'].'&week='.$row['week'].'&day='.$row['day'].'&shift='.$row['shift']?>" class="btn del">Cancel</a></td>
```

Also, in your SQL you're missing a column name, it should be `AND shift = $shift`.

You should also use a parametrized query instead of substituting variables, to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: and column name against the `$shift` parameter in query

Comment: Fixed that while you were commenting.

Comment: @HAHAHAHAHA i am glad that we could help and don't forget to accept the most helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

Look at your error messages.

Your `$_GET` array does not have the keys 'week' and 'day' because of your placement of ampersands.

It should be:

```
<td><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel Shift?')" href="remove.php? delete=<?php echo $row['employeeID'].'&week='$row['week'].'&day='$row['day'].'&shift='$row['shift']?>" class="btn del">Cancel</a></td>
```

Or more generically:

```
file.php?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

Unrelated, you're not using parameter binding, which you really should do, and you're not comparing `$shift` to anything in your SQL query.